# Rails 4 and Angularjs serialization issue

Tags: json, angularjs, serialization, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I'm having an issue when I try to send a json object to my create action in rails controller. The variables in my params are being interpreted as a string instead of a json object. Here is my code.

Angular Controller

```
rsn.controller(
'NewTeamController', [
    '$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
        // list of player son the team
        $scope.team = {name: '', league_id: '', players: []};

        // temp variables for adding a player
        $scope.player = {};

        $scope.addPlayer = function() {
            $scope.team.players.push($scope.player);

            $scope.player = {};

            console.log($scope.team);
        };

        $scope.saveTeam = function() {
            $http({method: 'POST', url: '/leagues/'+$scope.team.league_id+"/teams", params: {team: $scope.team}})
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log('It worked!');
                }
            );
        };

    }
]
```

);

Relevant Rails Controller Code

```
    class TeamsController < ApplicationController


  def create

    @team = Team.new(team_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @team.save
        format.html { redirect_to @team.league, notice: 'Team was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @team }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @team.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end


    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_league
      @team = Team.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def team_params
      params.require(:team).permit(:name, :league_id)
    end
end
```

When I run $scope.saveTeam() I'm getting the error "undefined method `permit' for #" for the permit call in the team_params function. In the error page the parameters section looks like this:

```
{"team"=>"{\"name\":\"\",\"league_id\":6,\"players\":[{\"name\":\"Dan\",\"email\":\"daniel.carpenter01@gmail.com\"}]}", "league_id"=>"6"}
```

Does anyone know why my params passed from angular are being interpreted as a string?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I was making the http post incorrectly from angular. Below is the $http code that worked correctly.

```
$http.post('/leagues/'+$scope.team.league_id+"/teams.json", {team: $scope.team}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Dan just a suggest: in your routes if you put the rule of resource like:

```
post 'leagues/:id'/teams, to: 'leagues#teams', defaults: { format: 'json' }
```

you can skip '.json' in your request

```
$http.post('/leagues/'+$scope.team.league_id+"/teams.json" => $http.post('/leagues/'+$scope.team.league_id+"/teams"
```

But your controller must respond json object.